# recording values of accelerometer in an excel file

Tags: javascript, expo, accelerometer

I want to record the values of accelerometer of a mobile in an excel file to use it for some Purposes. I'm getting these values by using the code available in the URL below: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/accelerometer/

Is it possible to get output directly into an excel file?